# How do you find the solutions for $(4n+3)^2-48y^2=1$?

Tags: pell-type-equations

I know that there are infinitly many because it is an Pell's equations, but how do I find the first? I have seen that we have $(1,1)$. But by solving it with the formula for finding the solutions, I arrive at $n$ not whole... Could someone explain me how to arrive at $n$ whole without just repeting the formula over and over again and just checking?

Comment: @user236182 Point taken, removing comment.

Answer (score 2):

The minimal solutions of the Pell equation 
$$ a^2-3b^2 = 1 \tag{1}$$
are given by the invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$, i.e. by the powers of $2\pm\sqrt{3}$
$$ a_n+b_n\sqrt{3} = (2+\sqrt{3})^n \tag{2} $$
so the solutions of $(1)$ are given by two sequences with the same recurrence relation:
$$ a_0 = 1,\quad a_1 = 2,\qquad a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-a_n, $$
$$ b_0 = 0,\quad b_1 = 1,\qquad b_{n+2}=4b_{n+1}-b_n, \tag{3}$$
but we are interested just in the solutions for which $a_n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and $b_2\equiv 0\pmod{4}$.
By studying the previous sequences $\!\!\pmod{4}$ it is easy to check that those constraints are equivalent to $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, hence the solutions of
$$ (4u+3)^2-16v^2 = 1 \tag{4}$$
are given by
$$ v_0 = 1,\quad v_1=195, \quad v_{n+2}=194 v_{n+1}-v_n \tag{5} $$
and
$$ u_0 = 1,\quad u_1=337,\quad (4u_{n+2}+3)= 194(4v_{n+1}+3)-(4v_n+3).\tag{6}$$

Comment: @igael: thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

What Jack said. Note that, while
$$ x_{j+2} = 14 x_{j+1} - x_j, $$ you need to take every other $x$ to get $3 \pmod 4.$ and
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
7 & 48 \\
1 & 7
\end{array}
\right)^2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
97 & 672 \\
14 & 97
\end{array}
\right).
$$ 
The trace of the first one is $14,$ but the trace of the second matrix is Jack's $194.$
$$ x_{j+4} = 194 x_{j+2} - x_j. $$ 
Probably better to start the list below with a line $x=1, y=0,$ but that would be some extra commands somewhere. Doing that would allow $18817 = 194 \cdot 97 - 1.$ Of course, you need only the $3 \pmod 4,$ so it starts $262087 = 194 \cdot 1351 - 7.$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$  ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    7   48
    1   7


  7^2 - 48 1^2 = 1

 x^2 - 48 y^2 = 1

Mon Sep 12 10:55:07 PDT 2016

x:  7  y:  1 ratio: 7  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  1 ,  0
x:  97  y:  14 ratio: 6.92857
x:  1351  y:  195 ratio: 6.92821
x:  18817  y:  2716 ratio: 6.9282
x:  262087  y:  37829 ratio: 6.9282
x:  3650401  y:  526890 ratio: 6.9282
x:  50843527  y:  7338631 ratio: 6.9282

Mon Sep 12 10:55:37 PDT 2016

 x^2 - 48 y^2 = 1

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```