# How do I prove that $\dfrac{(7+\sqrt{48})^n+(7-\sqrt{48})^n}{2}\equiv3\pmod4$ if and only if $n$ is odd?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

How do I prove that $\dfrac{(7+\sqrt{48})^n+(7-\sqrt{48})^n}{2}\equiv3\pmod4$ if and only if $n$ is odd?

I know that it will always be whole, and that it will never be $\equiv3$ if $n$ is even. But I want to know how to prove that it will always be $\equiv3$ if $n$ is odd...

Comment: Can you find the underlying recurrence?

Comment: Not specially... Could you help?

Comment: How about the quadratic that has solutions $7\pm\sqrt{48}$?

Comment: @Henry I'm not so familiar with that... Could you please give me the quadratic?

Comment: What methods do you know for questions like this? Recurrence relations and generating functions seem the most obvious to me.

Comment: Yea I know them but am quite new to them... But if you could be so kind to post an answer that is like $\pm$ detailed, I would be very pleased

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand both the terms using [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem). Following are the steps

$$\frac{ (7+\sqrt{48})^n + (7-\sqrt{48})^n}{2}$$

$$\frac{(7^n+7^{n-1}*\sqrt{48}+...\sqrt{48}^n)+(7^n-7^{n-1}*\sqrt{48}+...-\sqrt{48}^n)}{2}$$

It is seen   terms having *odd* power of $\sqrt{48}$ get cancelled. Left are even powers ( which get doubled ).

$$\frac{2*(7^n+7^{n-2}*\sqrt{48}^2+...+7*\sqrt{48}^{n-1})}{2}$$

The two gets cancelled. All even powers of $\sqrt{48}^{2k}$ make it $48^k$. Now $48$ is divisible by 4. Thus only term left is $7^n$, which is $3 \mod{4}$ when $n$ is odd ( as $7 \equiv 3 \mod{4}$, $7^2 \equiv 1 \mod{ 4}$, $7^3 \equiv 3 \mod {4}$ and so on ).

Comment: How do you come to that result? Could you please explain?

Comment: what part confuses you ? I used binomial expansion.

Comment: But could you please include more steps? I'm confused how you combined the two terms into one multiplication and how you canceled out some of the factors...

Comment: Ok will include more steps.

Comment: @DanielAlberten everything needed at my recent answer to  your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924054/how-do-you-find-the-solutions-for-4n32-48y2-1/1924162#1924162

Comment: Yea but it's complicated...

Comment: @DanielAlberten what is your actual background? Are you, by any chance, in high school?

Comment: @DanielAlberten Is it clear now ?

Comment: @sasha Yes but didn't you forget a $(7+\sqrt{48})$ and a $(7-\sqrt{48})$ in the factorisation?

Comment: @WillJagy Yes I am in High School and I don't understand the classes very well... It is difficult...

Comment: @DanielAlberten No. I don't understand your doubt. Maybe you could clear it in chat if you want.

Comment: @sasha Yes, how do I open one (or you can just do it but how do I join then?)

Comment: @DanielAlberten here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45280/binomial

Comment: 48 is divisible by 4.  so M*48^k is divisible by  4.  The only term of the big sum that is not divisible by 4 is $7^n$.  $7^n = (8 - 1)^n = 8^n - n8^7 + ..... n*8(-1)^{n-1}+ (-1)^n$.  The only term of *that* this is not divisible by 4 is $(-1)^n$.  So the remainder of the whole thing after dividing by 4 will be $(-1)^n$ (or $4 - (-1)^n$ if $(-1)^n < 0$).  $(-1)^n = 1$ if $n$ is even.  $(-1)^n = -1$ if $n$ is odd.  So remainder is $1$ if $n$ is even and is $3$ if $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments. Consider $a_n = \frac{(7+\sqrt{48})^n + (7-\sqrt{48})^n}{2}$. Then the characteristic equation of the reccurence relations is the one whose roots are $7+\sqrt{48}$ and $7 - \sqrt{48}$. It's not very difficult to notice that it's: $x^2 - 14x + 1 = 0$. Therefore we have: $a_n = 14a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$

Answer (score 1):

$(a \pm b)^n = a^n \pm n*a^{n-1}b + ...... + (-1)^i*{n \choose i}a^ib^{n-1}+ ....$.

So $(a -b)^n + (a+ b)^n = 2a^n + (n - n)a^{n-1}b + ...... (1 + (-1)^i){n \choose i}a^ib^{n-1}+....$.

$1 + (-1)^i = 0$ if $i$ is odd; $2$ if $i$ is even.

so $(a -b)^n + (a+ b)^n = 2(a^n + {n \choose 2}a^{n-2}b^2 + ...... {n \choose 2k}a^{n-2k}b^{2k}+....)$

So $N= \frac{(7 + \sqrt{48})^n + (7-\sqrt{48})}{2}= \sum_{k = 0;k \le n/2} {n \choose 2k}7^{n-2k}\sqrt{48}^{2k} = \sum_{k = 0;k \le n/2} {n \choose 2k}7^{n-2k}48^k$.

${n \choose 2k}7^{n-2k}48^k \equiv 0 \mod 4$ if $k \ne 0$. (Because $48\equiv 0 \mod 4$).

So $N= \sum_{k = 0;k \le n/2} {n \choose 2k}7^{n-2k}48^k \equiv {n \choose 0}7^n*48^0 = 7^n \equiv (-1)^n \mod 4$.

If $n$ is even $N \equiv (-1)^n \equiv 1 \not \equiv 3 \mod 4$.

If $n$ is odd $N \equiv (-1)^n \equiv -1 \equiv 3 \mod 4$